# S-voice on Samsung Galaxy S4 "No response from server..."

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, s-voice

I saw similar post about this problem from 5 days ago (8/15/13). That is also when S-voice stopped working on my Samsung Galaxy S4, even though it was working perfectly for the past 3 weeks. My internet connection is working.

I spent 1 1/2 hours with AT&T Tech Support and Samsung Tech Support on 8/17/13 and they could find no problems with my phone settings or internet connection.  However, Samsung tech suggested doing a master reset on my phone. I did not do this yet because I do not believe it is a problem with the phone, especially since I now see another posting for the problem occurring on the same day.

Is this a problem with an AT&T Server or is it Samsung?  How can we get someone to check this out?

**UPDATE 8/22/13:** I spent another 2 hours on phone 8/20/13 with new Samsung tech.  He was convinced that it was not my phone after he also checked all the postings about this problem online, so he "elevated" the "ticket" to a "system" problem.  Yesterday evening, I found that my S-voice just started working again!

Comment: What other posting?

Comment: The one from Enrico: S Voice "No response from the server. Please try again later".

Comment: Here it is: [S Voice “No response from the server. Please try again later”](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51253/16575). I'd say these two are a duplicate pair. Unfortunately, neither of them has an answer, so we cannot mark them.

Comment: @Izzy apparently onik didn't mind that the other one didn't have an answer =)

Comment: It is possible that there is a server down, it's possible that the functionality returns in a couple of days. I would not try a factory reset right away just in case it is a wasted effort.

Comment: @John With good reason. While "normal" community members (like me) cannot close such questions as duplicates, diamonds can. I asked the "diamonds" to please handle it this way, and onik is one of them :)

Comment: @Izzy oh alright, why did you flag the other one to be closed? That one was posted first so this one technically the duplicate.

Comment: This one showed more details as pointers for answers.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue with S-Voice on my Samsung Galaxy S4 all of a sudden. A Samsung support tech helped me figure it out by telling me to start the phone in Safe Mode to see if S-Voice worked that way.  He said if it did, it was most likely a 3rd party app.  Turns out he was right.  I deleted Music Download Paradise Pro, which was the most recent app I had downloaded and S-Voice has worked since then.